# namely the occupation of the disks from " pantheon files" or from the desktop

Tags: pantheon-files

exite any way to know in " pantheon Files" occupation of records, something like " My Computer" windows , currently use the df from the terminal , but I wonder if there from the graphical environment otherwise.
Regards, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In Loki, you can right click on the devices in the sidebar of Files and choose "Properties" to get information about device size and usage.  This causes the device to be mounted though and only gives the information for one device at a time, so it is not exactly equivalent to df.  Is this what you were asking?

Comment: hi, Jeremy, yes this is that i ask, but in Freya?

Comment: In Freya the only way I know is to navigate to the root directory of the drive and then right click on the background in the view. The "Properties" option should give the device usage.